# Remove manually typed numbers when applying a numbered style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

If there is a manually typed number in an unstyled paragraph, how can I ensure that when applying a numbered style, I do not get duplicate numbers?

Before applying style

[image: No style]

After applying style

[image: With style]

Style definition:

```
  Font color: Black, Indent:
        Left:  1.5 cm
        Hanging:  1.5 cm, Level 3
        Tab stops:  3 cm, List tab, Outline numbered + Level: 3 + Numbering Style: 1, 2, 3, … + Start at: 1 + Alignment: Left + Aligned at:  1.5 cm + Tab after:  3 cm + Indent at:  3 cm
        Based on: BaseStyle
```

This is just an example but it happens for all styles with legal numbering like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard find and replace to apply your styles and at the same time delete the manual numbering.
[image]

[0-9] means find any digit.  As your clause numbering may have more than one digit, you also want to find any number of digits which is done by adding the @ after the closing square bracket.  Then that number will always be followed by a full stop.  The ^t is to find the tab which you also want to delete, assuming your outline numbering for Paragraph 1.1.1 style includes the tab after.

The () create separate parts of your find result which you can refer to.

We want to find the numbers, full stops and tab as one part, and then keep the remaining text as the other part (which is found by the wildcard *).

So in the replace with we want to just keep part 2 which is done by \2 and also apply our outline numbered style.

Rather than a replace all, I step through by using find next and replace one at a time (rather than replace all), to make sure you don't inadvertently replace something that should be a different level or is in body of text with rogue tab following.  Also with your numbering, you'll want to start with the "lowest" level that your documents uses (eg 1.1.1.1.1) so that you don't inadvertently replace with the wrong style by finding 1.1.1 as part of 1.1.1.1.1.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you. I will mark it as the answer. I was wondering though - if there is anything more automated within Word, rather than having to manually find/replace.